# sql login failed for windows authentication

Tags: sql, windows-services

I have a windows service which will try to check the sql server is available or not using windows authentication. But the service is not able to connect to sql server. It is throwing an error "Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection". The same application when i try to execute from console my application is able to connect to sql server using windows authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Under which account your service is running? If that service is running as say LocalService account, it is not authorized to login to SQL. Change the account under which windows service runs.